# Using find function to print line and character location on line

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am a new coder trying to figure out how to use the find() command to search for a chunk of text, word, or letter in a multi-lined code. So if the input was

> I like dogs.
>
> I have a dog too.

Then I'm aiming to print something like:

> Dog found on line 1 at character 7
>
> Dog found on line 2 at character 9

So far I have

```
chunk = input('Enter chunk: ')
        for line in data.split("\n"):    #data is the block of text to be searched
            for word in line.split():
```

(Not sure what to do after this)  I have tried

```
print(word.find(chunk))
```

but that only outputs the last character that the chunk appears at.

```
            if chunk in i:
                print(chunk, 'on line number {} at character {}',x,y)
```

I  know this is how I need to print but am not sure how I establish x and y variables either.

All help appreciated, Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the substring is found within the string, `find` will return its position. If not, it returns -1. Here is how you can use `find`:

```
for j, line in enumerate(data.splitlines()):
    pos = line.find(chunk)
    if pos != -1:
        print('{0} found on line {1} at character {2}'.format(chunk, j, pos))
```

Comment: Maybe explain what `find` returns and the alternative of using `index`.

Comment: Thanks, this worked.  A related small question I have is what it means when you use both 'j' and 'line' after the for statement.  I understand j will give the line number it appears, but how do I know when to use two variables after a for command as opposed to one?

Comment: @chillbro You're welcome. You can use two variables because `enumerate` will yield a tuple containing two variables at each iteration. You could have used one variable but the variable would have been a tuple with 2 elements.